# What is the name of this Hunter x Hunter (2011) song in episode 20?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

In *Hunter x Hunter* (2011) episode 20, there's music playing on around 03:21.

What is the name of the song?

Answer (score 1):

The song playing during 3:23-5:27 is known as `Unreleased Departure Instrumental Variation #1`

It is not part of the official released ost, and is a play on the song [Departure for strings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RowCrLrWiOQ).
Which was included as the [25th track in OST 2](https://sites.google.com/site/hxh2011ostlist/cd-s/ost-2?authuser=0)

[Source](https://sites.google.com/site/hxh2011ostlist/arcs/home)